# I get this error when running a customtkinter app: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm making a GUI app in customtkinter, but each time a try to run the app it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\main.pyw", line 9, in <module>
    app = App()
          ^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\main.pyw", line 6, in __init__
    self.geometry('400x300')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\ctk_tk.py", line 194, in geometry
    super().geometry(self._apply_geometry_scaling(geometry_string))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\scaling\scaling_base_class.py", line 134, in _apply_geometry_scaling
    assert self.__scaling_type == "window"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2410, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
                   ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2410, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
                   ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2410, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
                   ^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Here's the code for the gui app:

```
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__
        self.geometry('400x300')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Tried changing the maximum recrusion depth to 2000, it stopped displaying the error but the app doesn't want to open at all.

Comment: You have a typo here: `super().__init__` should be `super().__init__()` (add the parentheses)

Comment: `super().__init__` should be `super().__init__()`, for one thing

Comment: Oh thank's, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`super().__init__` should be `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 0):

I think its a syntax error. Somewhere between the line 4-5. Try using debugger to eliminate the syntax error.